# Wordpress image gallery attachment page image don't show

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have created an image gallery (Select attachment page from gallery setting Link to option) on photo gallery page. Image gallery shortcode like this:

```
[gallery link="post" columns="2" ids="25,13"]
```

I used wordpress 3.5 and my current theme is Twenty Eleven.

When I click photo gallery page then page open correctly without any error. But When I click on photo gallery image that I inserted as a gallery then my request go to the following url: `http://localhost/wordpress/?attachment_id=25` and show the following error message: `This is somewhat embarrassing, isn’t it?`
any one can tell me how can I solve this problem. Thanks

Comment: I have exactly the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same issue it is related to .htaccess. I removed the .htaccess and it gets recreated and the problem should be fixed.